# Azure - Invalid header for rest request in worker role

Tags: c#, azure

Im having problems when executing `blobcontainer.CreateIfNotExist();` in my worker role stating this :

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

At the beggining I thought that the problem could be my local computer date (since im from south america)  so I added  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` but the error continued..

The way im getting the configuration for my connection with the storage is like this :

```
 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("dataconnectionstring"));
```

Which is :

```
<Setting name="dataconnectionstring" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
               AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
               AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" />
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your connection string. I see that you're trying to connect to development storage (storage emulator):

```
<Setting name="dataconnectionstring" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
           AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
           AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" />
```

For connecting to development storage, please specify the connection string in the following format:

```
<Setting name="dataconnectionstring" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

Please use the format that you're using to specify connection to a cloud storage account.

Comment: that was my first try.. whenever I place useDevelopmentStorage=true it throws : WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 31-Mar-13 1:28:13 AM.
[Diagnostics]: Signalling process restart on event = WADDM-ShutDown-434ade335f514cb8bbc5901cab962f36

Comment: I see. A quick search for this `ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)` error led me to this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/20/winhttpgetproxyforurl-failed-error-winhttp-autodetection-failed-12180-error-message-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-log.aspx. However based on the post, this should not create an exception. Can you try connecting to actual cloud storage account and see if you're still getting the same error? Also, what's the version of SDK you're using? Also check if you're connecting from behind a proxy server?

Comment: It seems to be working fine on the cloud but it still fails on the emulator, im using the emulator version 1.8 and the api v1.7

Comment: One thing you could do is trace the requests to storage emulator in Fiddler. In order to do so, please specify the connection string as: `UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler`. The response should give you more details about the error which you can then post in the original question above so that we can find exactly why you're getting the error. HTH.

Comment: "The server encountered an unknown failure: The remote name could not be resolved: 'ipv4.fiddler'" that is the current error im getting :(

Comment: Is Fiddler installed on your computer?